# Using SQL when multiple versions of Excel are installed

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel 2007, 2010 and 2016 installed on one PC. In Excel 2007 or 2010, when running VBA that uses SQL to query data in the same workbook, the PC launches Excel 2016 which seems to handle the SQL query. This makes the query very slow and leaves me with a read-only copy of the workbook open in Excel 2016. Is there a way to force Excel to use the already opened instance to process the SQL?

This is the code that creates the ADODB Connection:

```
Public Function GetDbConn(ByRef theXlFilePathAndName As String) As ADODB.Connection

Dim connDB As ADODB.Connection

Set connDB = New ADODB.Connection
connDB.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='" & theXlFilePathAndName & "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR = YES'"
Set GetDbConn = connDB

End Function
```

Comment: Sure, basicly with ActiveWorkbook and eventually RefersToLocal. Kinda based on your code. If you share the line there you open the conection we might be able to help you.

Comment: Instead of theXlFilePathAndName use ActiveWorkbook and RefersToLocal. If you define a path like that, it will open the file newly. While open it new it chooses your standard software which is excel 2017. You can also define it with ading an options string behind the string.

Comment: @Doomenik - can you please provide an example? The only times I have seen RefersToLocal is to simply return the string of the address of a named range.